# Creating Table/LaTeX with Extreme Points based on parameter values in a table

Tags: mathematical-optimization, export, output-formatting

I would like to simulate extreme points and illustrate results with exogenous parameters and optimal values. I created the input table and table with the optimization problem for a simplified example.

How can I format the output of the value and optimal values (x,y,v,z in the example) as separate columns so I can export to CSV or create a LaTeX table? Meaning listing the values without {, }, ", and ,.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Clear["Global`*"]
inputs = {
  {1, -3},
  {2, -3.5}
 }
newtable = Table[
   {
    inputs[[row, 1]],
    inputs[[row, 2]],
    {f[x_, y_, v_, z_] := (x + inputs[[row, 1]])^2 + 
       inputs[[row, 2]]*y + v*z;
     g1[x_, y_] := 2 x + y - 10;
     g2[v_, z_] := v + z - 5;
     FullSimplify@
      ToRadicals@
       Maximize[{f[x, y, v, z], g1[x, y] == 0, g2[v, z] == 0, x >= 0, 
         y >= 0, v >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, v, z}, Reals]}
    },
   {row, 1, Length[inputs]}
   ];
table = Grid[newtable]
Export["table.txt", table, "CSV"]
```

The output from the optimization problem is

1,-3,"{{169/4, {x -> 5, y -> 0, v -> 5/2, z -> 5/2}}}"

2,-3.5,"{{55.25, {x -> 5., y -> 0., v -> 2.4999999979968663, z -> 2.5000000020031337}}}"

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[in1_, in2_, x_, y_, v_, z_] :=
  (x + in1)^2 + in2*y + v*z;
g1[x_, y_] := 2 x + y - 10;
g2[v_, z_] := v + z - 5;

inputs = {{1, -3}, {2, -3.5}} // Rationalize;
```

Do not include display wrappers such as `Grid` within the definition of a variable. Use parentheses to isolate the wrapper from the definition.

```
(table =
   Prepend[
    Flatten[
       {#, {#[[1]], Values[#[[2]]]} &@
         Maximize[{f[#[[1]], #[[2]], x, y, v, z],
           g1[x, y] == 0, g2[v, z] == 0,
           x >= 0, y >= 0, v >= 0, z >= 0},
          {x, y, v, z}, Reals]}] & /@
     inputs,
    {"in1", "in2", "opt", "x", "y", "v", "z"}]) //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

To convert the rationals to reals

```
Export["table.csv", table /. r_Rational :> N[r, 4], "CSV"]

(* "table.csv" *)

Import["table.csv"] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]